# GetDriveType in C#? or find out if my drive is removable?

Tags: c#, removable-storage, getdrivetype

I am using Environment.GetLogicalDrives(); to get a list of drives. I remember in c++ i could use GetDriveType to find if the device was CD, removable, flash, etc and i am thinking i want to put a filter in my app to only show CD and removable on default. What is the GetDriveType equivalent in C#? google only showed me hacks to use the c++ call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the framework includes a [DriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.drivetype.aspx) enumeration used by the [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) class. Have a look at the [GetDrives()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) method on MSDN.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [DriveInfo type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) to retrieve a list of the drives. You need to check the [DriveType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype.aspx) (enum)

```
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (var drive in drives)
{
    if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(drive.Name);
    }
}
```

You can also use LINQ-to-Objects to query the drives:

```
var drives = from drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
             where drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable
             select drive;

foreach(var drive in drives)
{
    Console.WriteLine(drive.Name);
}
```

Like the @TheCodeKing mentioned you can also use WMI to query drive information.

For example, you can query for USB sticks in the following manner:

```
ManagementObjectCollection drives = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    "SELECT Caption, DeviceID FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'"
).Get();
```

Add a reference to the System.Management assembly if you are going to use WMI.

If you want to fill a ComboBox in a Windows Forms application with this data you need to bind the results to the ComboBox control.

For example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var drives = from drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                 where drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable
                 select drive;

    comboBox1.DataSource = drives.ToList();
}
```

To recapitulate:

1. Add a ComboBox control to the Windows Form (drag & drop it on the form from the Toolbox)
2. Query the removable drives.
3. Bind the results to the ComboBox.

Comment: Also note that if you want to include CD-Rom drives, they aren't considered 'Removable' in the `DriveType` enumeration.  You might also want to check `|| drive.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom`

Comment: thank you all for your help but could anyone tell me how to add a drop down menu in my c# winform application and then fill it with the drivers labels and letters

Comment: Updated my answer to show how you can bind these results to a ComboBox control in a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 2):

[DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) is the class you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have use WMI for this, check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for for information and examples.

Comment: +1 for mentioning WMI. Here's an example using WMI to query drive information: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial233_Getting-Disk-Drive-Information-using-WMI-and-Csharp.html