# Determine the type of storage media in C#

Tags: c#, windows-7, sd-card, usb-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GetDriveType in C#? or find out if my drive is removable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623254/getdrivetype-in-c-or-find-out-if-my-drive-is-removable)

I want to know whether an inserted storage media is a flash card or a USB stick. Windows 7 knows this, because it shows nice icons for the disk. How can C# access this information?

[image: DriveImages]

I have looked at ManagementObjectSearcher, ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent") and DriveInfo, but none of these gives this type of information as far as I can see.

Comment: Are you sure this information is even known to Windows?  At the end of the day a flash card and an USB flash device are exactly the same to windows a removable device.

Comment: The link (I marked as duplicate) can identify the differences between something like a CD drive, and removable storage, but not the different types of removable storage. But your question is not about the types of removalbe storage but about the difference between storage devices. I hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: I don't think this is the same question as the link. DriveInfo cannot give me the information I need. And, yes, windows knows because it displays the correct icon in Windows Explorer.